# How to create a new document of bill doctype each time a customer completes an order

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I am completely new to Frappe framework and have never dealt with backend or API before
I was assigned the following task, which is when the customer clicks on the Submit button to complete his order, a new document from bill doctype should be generated with the details of order and inserted into the database

My question is that I need clear steps to carry out this task as I feel completely lost. Where should I start? or how can I send a request to the server after the customer clicks the submit button?

I would be grateful to anyone who can show me the steps or even share resources that I can use to get the task done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code snippet in the Server Script.

Script Type: DocType Event
DocType: Sales Order
DocType Event: After Submit

```
        docPE = frappe.get_doc(dict(
            doctype = 'Payment Entry',
            docstatus = 1,
            mode_of_payment = "Cash",
            paid_amount = PAID_AMOUNT,
            party_type = "Customer",
            party = doc.customer,
            payment_type = "Receive",
            payment_order_status = "Initiated",
            received_amount = PAID_AMOUNT,
            make_payment_via_journal_entry = 0,
            source_exchange_rate = 1,
            target_exchange_rate = 1,
            paid_to = "PAID_TO_ACCOUNT",
            paid_to_account_currency = "CURRENCY",
            paid_to_account_type = "Cash",
            reference_date = doc.transaction_date,
            reference_no = "1",
            references = [{
                "doctype": "Payment Entry Reference",
                "allocated_amount": PAID_AMOUNT,
                "reference_doctype": "Sales Order",
                "reference_name": doc.name,
                "parentfield": "references",
                "parenttype": "Payment Entry",
                "exchange_rate": 1
            }]
        )).insert()
        frappe.msgprint("The Payment Entry " + docPE.name + " is created.")
```

PS1: It is not "Bill" doctype, it is "Payment Entry".
PS2: You may also need to cancel the payment if sales order is cancelled.
PS3: You need to fill the PAID_AMOUNT and PAID_ACCOUNT sections.